# Remove queries from For loop

Tags: apex, query, lookup, for

I have a batch class

```
global Database.queryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){

    return Database.getQueryLocator('Select Field1__c, Field_2 from  Object1__c where Status__c in (\'New\', \'Retry\') );
}

global void execute (Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Object1__c> object1List){

    for(Object1__c  object1 : object1List){
        List<Account> account = [select Id from Account where SCH_ID__c=:object1__c.Field1__c];
    }
```

Here Field1__c is not a lookup field. I would like to understand if I can move the query out of the for loop without the use of a map. i tried the use of teh following but it needs a reference field to work

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice:_Avoid_SOQL_Queries_Inside_FOR_Loops

Comment: What's the relationship between `Account` and `Object1__c`? Or is it just the `Field1__c` is some text linked to `Account` and Why you don't want to use a `map` is there any specific reason to avoid using `map`. What the further logic in the for loop with account list?

Comment: Using a `Map` is a standard bulkification pattern and you don't have to have a lookup field in place to apply it.

Comment: Could you clarify if the query in the loop always returns one result or can return many results?  You can replace a `Map` with a `List` and just loop through to find the Account you're looking for, but there's no good reason to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Considering `Field1__c` has `id` values, i.e. 15 or 18 digit Salesforce Ids, then you can create a `Set<Id>` and feed it to your SOQL. You could do something like

```
Set<Id> schIds = new Set<id>();
for(Object1__c  object1 : object1List){
    schIds.add(object1__c.Field1__c);
}
if(shcIds.size() > 0) {
    List<Account> account = [select Id from Account where 
    SCH_ID__c IN: schIds];
}
```